# How to count the number of rows in a crossTab in Cognos

Tags: count, row, crosstab, cognos

Simply put, i have this crossTab with rows and columns and manually created measure. Everything seems to work fine.

I now simply need to count the numbers of rows it displays for each ROW values.

ROWS from left to right:    ItemCountry, Manager
Columns from left to right: Choice#1, Choice#2, Choice#3
Measure:QTY for each [Choice#1], [Choice#2], [Cjoice#3]

I now need: Nb of rows for by ItemCountry, Manager
I now need: sum of [Choice#1], [Choice#2],[Choice#3] by ItemCountry and by Manager

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate if you've tried count distinct and found it wanting.

I'm at a bit of a handicap as your last two paragraphs are not necessarily as clearly stated as one might hope, unfortunately.  In particular, but not exclusively, it's not clear what Choice#3,  Choice#2, and  Choice#1 are.

Comment: Hello, basically, can i have TOTALS or counts for EACH ROW of my crossTab ?

Comment: Thanks for putting the picture onto Cognoise but it looked like a list report rather than a crosstab.   It may be that you cut and pasted stuff but that picture is confusing to me.

You get summaries for free in a crosstab IIRC.  

If you want to know the number of values for any particular thing you could add a calculation whose expression is count or count distinct (depending on what you are seeking).  You don't mention if you've tried that or not and what happened.

So basically, I'm not much further along then before understanding what you are seeking.

Comment: thanks once again for your replies. Yes it is a crossTab that i made appear as a LIST and Yes i did tried count ( [Manager] for [ItemCountry]) and something strange happens as for i get the correct number of rows but on the far right most cell instead instead of the far left cell + i also get (already had this one working) the SUM of the rows but instead of being displayed on the far right cell (as i want) it is being displayed on the far left cell. I'm kind of almost there but not quite there yet.

Comment: Do you mean left vs right adjust on the cell property?